# Group pandas df by every n rows with most frequent entry in column y for each set of n rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mesa

I'm working in a Python / Mesa environment and producing agent-based model output data which looks like the following:


[image: Simulation output data]

25920 rows by 11 columns. The df is sorted by the columns of which I've performed parametric runs producing all combinations of them: density, hero_prob, malevolent, tipping_point, agi_gain

The parameter space is 2592 and with 10 replications per combination...thus 25920 rows. What I am trying to do is create a new df for logistic regression which condenses every 10 rows of a given parameter combination with the **most frequent entry for 'Engage' remains.**

Thus, I'd end up a new 2592 x 11 df where the first row would be the same as the row with RunId value 2 above since all of those 'Engage' entries are False. A later parameter set with 7 True and 3 False would condense to a row with those parameter settings and True in the engage column for example. I tried the following code:

`df_grouped = df_sorted.groupby(['density','hero_prob','malevolent','tipping_point','agi_gain'])['Engage'].agg(pd.Series.mode).to_frame()`

But the results confuse me and I only have an Engage column, not the parameter settings. And agi_gain appears combined:

[image: Confusing results]
That structure isn't like my original df, which is what I'm trying to circle back to, but just condensed with the most common 'Engage' result.

**Bonus:** In the event of 5 True, 5 False for a given parametric combination an "Engage" entry of "Tie" would be amazing. Thank you as always to this amazing community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since parameters in the group are all the same, it is possible to just use mode:

```
df_sorted.groupby(parameter_columns).agg(pd.Series.mode)
```

For the tie support, an aggregation function would look something like:

```
def tie_mode(series):
    counts = series.value_counts()
    if len(counts) == 1:  # a parameter column or all same results
        return next(iter(series))
    if counts.get(False) == counts.get(True):
        return 'tie'
    return counts.get(True, 0) > counts.get(False, 0)

df_sorted.groupby(parameter_columns).agg(my_agg)
```

Comment: You're saying remove the .to_frame() from the end? Doing so produces a similar product to what isn't making sense, specifically the fact that all age_gain options seem to be lumped together. I'm editing the original post shortly to show the results.

Comment: @Clark I'm not sure how is `.to_frame()` applicable here, but the screenshot looks about what you describe as the desired outcome. Note that whatever you group on becomes a [multilevel] index, so perhaps you'd want to add `.reset_index()` at the end to get a familiarly looking dataframe

Comment: Adding ```.reset_index()``` did it! Thank you. I wasn't familiar with a [multilevel] index (though the idea makes sense), so the original output was confusing me.